# Selenium driver on google next button, NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script that deals with google. I have successfully searched for what I wanted using the selenium web driver however I would like to navigate to the next page of results. my code looks as follows:

```
import parameters
import csv

from parsel import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
empty=""
def validate_field(field):
    if field == "":
        field= 'No results'
    return field 



writer=csv.writer(open(parameters.file_name, 'w'))
writer.writerow(('Name','Job Title','Company','College','Location','URL'))

driver=webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')
username=driver.find_element_by_id('session_key') #locating the email form using the class name
username.send_keys('')
sleep(0.5)
password=driver.find_element_by_id('session_password') #locating the password form using the class name
password.send_keys('')
sleep(0.5)
log_in_button=driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign-in-form__submit-button') #locating submit button by class name
log_in_button.click() #here we are mimicing a click
sleep(0.5)
driver.get('https:www.google.com') #navigating to google
sleep(3)
search_gog=driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_gog.send_keys(parameters.search_gog)
sleep(0.5)
search_gog.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(3)

list_links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='g']//div[@class='r']/a[contains(@href, 'https://www.linkedin.com')]")]

    for link in list_links:
        driver.get(link)
        sel=Selector(text=driver.page_source)
        name = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words")]/text()').extract_first()
        if name:
            name=name.strip()
        job_title= sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "mt1 t-18 t-black t-normal break-words")]/text()').extract_first()
        if job_title:
            job_title=job_title.strip()

        education = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "pv-profile-section-pager ember-view")]/text()').extract_first()
        if education:
            education=education.strip()
        name=validate_field(name)
        job_title=validate_field(job_title)
        education=validate_field(education)

   
        print('\n')
        print('Name: ' + name)
        print('Job Title: ' + job_title)
        print('Education: ' + education)
        print(education)
        print('URL: ' + driver.current_url)
        print('\n')
   


driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()
```

the parameters file contains the google search query which states:

```
search_gog = 'site:linkedin.com/in/ AND "data analyst" AND "California"'
```

upon running the above I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app2.py", line 79, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()
  File "/Users/rubenolmos/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "/Users/rubenolmos/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Users/rubenolmos/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/rubenolmos/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Next"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

I have also tried using the html code for the element which is:

```
<a href="/search?q=site:linkedin.com/in/+AND+%22data+analyst%22+AND+%22California%22&amp;ei=lbpbX4GhDoPs9APDmITID
A&amp;start=10&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjBv57e1uHrAhUDNn0KHUMMAckQ8NMDegQICxA_" 
id="pnnext" style="text-align:left"><span class="SJajHc NVbCr" 
style="background:url(/images/nav_logo299_hr.webp) no-repeat;background-position:-96px 
0;background-size:167px;width:71px"></span><span style="display:block;margin-
left:53px">Next</span></a>
```

using the above html element I have tried finding the element using the element id "pnnext' by doing the following find_element_by_id("pnnext").click and it has been unsuccessful.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should hide your email address and password if they are real.

Comment: I made the account as a throw away for this project. changed it to avoid having to make another throwaway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you have `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`, then when you do `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()` following `search_gog.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`, the driver will wait for up to 10 seconds for the next page to load and a link with the text "Next" to appear before throwing an exception. So, the call to `sleep(3)` that you invoke between the two calls is rather superfluous. If for whatever reason you thought 10 seconds was not enough (hard to believe for google.com), then just increase the amount of time on the call to `driver.implicitly_wait`.

I cannot tell what your search argument to Google is, but it just may be possible that the number of returned results isn't enough to warrant a "Next" link. Modify your code as follows:

```
search_gog.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
next_links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Next") # note it is find_elements with an s
if len(next_links):
    next_links[0].click()
else:
    print('There is no "Next" link')
```

**Update**

I have run the following code on my desktop 5 times in a row and each time it has successfully navigated to the second page (that is, it has found the "Next" link and clicked on it successfully).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com') #navigating to google
    search_gog=driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    search_gog.send_keys('site:linkedin.com/in/ AND "data analyst" AND "California"')
    search_gog.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    next_links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Next") # note it is find_elements with an s
    if len(next_links):
        print('Found "Next" link')
        next_links[0].click()
    else:
        print('There is no "Next" link')
finally:
    input('pausing (hit enter to terminate) ...')
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I got a "There is no Next link" how should this be modified then

Comment: Get rid headless mode if you are using it and add a "pause" with `input('pausing ...')` following the `print('There is no "Next" link')` to look at the actual query results and see if it make sense. Perhaps your input string to the query is wrong, so you can print that out, too.

Comment: I am not quite exactly what you mean. I am really new to selenium and web drivers. Are you referring to the query results from google. I have verified that the google results are valid. I added the pausing line of code and it just gave gave me the same result with a line that says pausing .... The program does not seem to output anything just stay at the pausing

Comment: Yes, look at the query result from Google. Do you see a "Next" link? If you do, use the browser's inspection capability to look at the link to make sure that the link contains just "Next" and nothing else. If you do not see the "Next" link, is it because there is only one page worth of results? If so, why is that a problem? The program will stay at "pausing" until you enter anything followed by the enter key. This was just to prevent the program form terminating and having the browser window closing.

Comment: Hi thanks I read up on the pausing input I understand. I put the html code above, after the results are searched for there is a Next link at the bottom of the page. The html code that I provided above is that of what is found when using the inspect capabilities of chrome. There are multiple results for the query as well. I have navigated to multiple pages and they all hold the same form. I was thinking of specifying the hrefs and selecting selecting for only those that had the link form of the next.

Comment: If I knew what your actual search query string was, I might understand more about what was going on.

Comment: I updated my question a while ago with the actual query, its the second block of code.By the way thanks a lot you are getting me closer to the solution

Comment: Actually, I can see it now from the stack trace encoded.

Comment: There is some code in between driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click() and sleep(3) but its just navigating to the the urls and extracting information. Do you think that can have an impact on this error ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with code that runs consistently successfully. All I can say is that you should compare it carefully with yours.

Answer (score 0):

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException means it can't find the element it may be caused by elements takings too long to load or a wrong XPath. There might be an iframe as well.

```
elem=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID('pnnext')))
elem.click()
```

Import these.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi I got the error that id is not an attribute of By